# How to implement google reCaptcha v2 in spring framework

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, recaptcha

My reCaptcha in the registration screen is not working anymore since the google has been shutdown reCaptcha v1 .

Can somebody tell me how to implement reCaptcha v2 in my spring application. Does anyone know any documentation link?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display).

Beside that there is an open source project for easy reCAPTCHA integration in Spring: https://github.com/Mr-DeWitt/spring-boot-recaptcha. With the simplest use case you just have to set the captcha validated URLs in your app config file, and you are ready to go.